# Concatenate Parts of Later Substrings, and Delete those Substrings

Tags: python, regex

I am a newbie in python.I have a text file where i need to concatenate the string within () and delete after concat.

text.txt

```
Car(skoda,benz,bmw,audi)
The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
......

Car(Rangerover,Hummer)
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

Desired output

```
Car(skoda,benz,bmw,audi,Rangerover,Hummer)
The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
......
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```

here the Car should be addding to the first Car inside brackets and then delete the line i have concatenated.

Coding:

```
f_in=open("text.txt", "r")      
in_lines=f_in.readlines()           
out=[]
for line in in_lines:
    list_values=line.split()       
    for 'Car' in line:
        Car[i]=eval(list_values[i])    
        if Car[i] in line:     
            str(Car+Car[i]) #i m stuck and my overall logic is getting worse'
```

Please help in getting me the desired output.due to lack of experience i dont know the simmplest way of getting this.Answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Figure out how you would do it by hand first, *then* write code.

Answer (score 1):

### Tricky Replacement

Search:

```
(?s)^(Car\([^),]+(,)[^)]*)(?=.*?Car\(([^)]+)\))|(?!^)Car\([^)]*\)[\r\n]*
```

Replace:

```
\1\2\3
```

In **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bN9zK9/3)**, see the substitutions at the bottom.

If there are more than two Car definitions, run this replacement until the result string is identical to the original string.

**Sample Python Code**

```
subject=""
result= // paste your original string
while result != subject:
    subject = result
    result = re.sub(r"(?s)^(Car\([^),]+(,)[^)]*)(?=.*?Car\(([^)]+)\))|(?!^)Car\([^)]*\)[\r\n]*",
                    r"\1\2\3",
                    subject)
```

Comment: as i am newbie,could u post as how do i access it by opening a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use re to find all cars then write the lines excluding the lines with Car:

```
import re
comp = re.compile('([^\(]*)\)')
with open("in.txt") as f, open("amended.txt","w") as f1:
    lines = f.read() # read line into one string
    cars = re.findall(comp,lines) # find all cars
    joined = " ".join([" ".join(x.split(",")) for x in cars]) # join all cars inside one set of parens
    f1.write("Car({})\n".format(joined)) # write cars to first line
    f.seek(0) # go back to start
    for line in f:
        if "Car(" not in line: # ignore lines with Car(....
            f1.write("{}".format(line))
```

It outputs:

```
Car(skoda benz bmw audi Rangerover Hummer)
The above mentioned cars are sedan type and gives long rides efficient
SUV cars are used for family time and spacious.
```